# Migrate from npm to yarn concerning the modules installed globally

Tags: npm, node-modules, yarnpkg

Just found out that yarn does not install same modules again and again in different projects and so you can recover some space from the hard drive, so my question...Is there a way to transfer or migrate npm modules installed globally to yarn and what exactly should be done, in every single project, which previously got it's dependancies through npm?